# Can't print specific part of JSON using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, json, ssjs

I'm trying to retrieve a specific part (attribute Region) of JSON I receive and print it. Apparently, I'm missing something. I would really appreciate your advice.

```
Platform.Load("core","1"); 
var ip = Platform.Request.ClientIP(); 
var apiKey = 'Key_is_inserted_here';
var url = 'https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=';
var response = HTTP.Get(url + apiKey + "&ipAddress=" + ip);
Write("response.Status: " + response.Status + '<br />');
Write("response.Content: " + response.Content);
Write(String(response.Content.location.region));
```

The response I receive looks like this:

```
{
    "ip": "176.114.240.35",
    "location": {
        "country": "CZ",
        "region": "Hlavní město Praha",
        "city": "Malá Strana",
        "lat": 50.0877,
        "lng": 14.4045,
        "postalCode": "",
        "timezone": "+01:00",
        "geonameId": 3071213
    },
    "as": {
        "asn": 202618,
        "name": "rychlydrat",
        "route": "176.114.240.0/20",
        "domain": "",
        "type": ""
    },
    "isp": "Rychlý drát"
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the parse json function: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformUtilityParseJSON.htm

Comment: What is displayed with the above or does it error?

Comment: @EazyE Well, I think it does the opposite from what I try to achieve. It's a parsing of string to create an object.

Comment: @Gortonington the last write returns "undefined"

Comment: Can you put up a full return of response. Is Content an array holding the object you show? Need to see exactly what you are working with to find the issue

Comment: @Gortonington the whole response looks like this: response.Status: 0
response.Content: {"ip":"176.114.240.35","location":{"country":"CZ","region":"Hlavn\u00ed m\u011bsto Praha","city":"Mal\u00e1 Strana","lat":50.0877,"lng":14.4045,"postalCode":"","timezone":"+01:00","geonameId":3071213},"as":{"asn":202618,"name":"rychlydrat","route":"176.114.240.0\/20","domain":"","type":""},"isp":"Rychl\u00fd dr\u00e1t"}undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your comments, I am going to assume that Content is returned in an array:

```
[{
    "ip": "176.114.240.35",
    "location": {
        "country": "CZ",
        "region": "Hlavní město Praha",
        "city": "Malá Strana",
        "lat": 50.0877,
        "lng": 14.4045,
        "postalCode": "",
        "timezone": "+01:00",
        "geonameId": 3071213
    },
    "as": {
        "asn": 202618,
        "name": "rychlydrat",
        "route": "176.114.240.0/20",
        "domain": "",
        "type": ""
    },
    "isp": "Rychlý drát"
}]
```

In which you would need to adjust your approach in order to gather the value from the Content part.  You would need to add the object number to the array call (`Content`) even if it is only a single object in it.

Like this: `response.Content[0].location.region` Which should now return the value you required.

The only other option I can think of is that SFMC has stringified the internal object, in which case you would need to do the following to turn it back into an object and not a string:

```
var content = ParseJSON(response.Content)
var region = content.location.region
```

Or potentially some combination there of should give you what you need.